# sonarqube maven plugin failing without message

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using `SonarQube 6.5 (build 27846)` and `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar` goal. I'm launching via Jenkins FreeStyle project where I just invoke Apache Maven 3.5.1 directly, and we're using OpenJDK 1.8 on Linux. My jobs that run Sonar for a variety of projects are failing intermittently without any warning message. Here's the tail of the output:

```
[INFO] 14:07:10.440 Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[DEBUG] 14:07:10.441 Work directory: /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/sonar_com.acme.project/target/sonar
[DEBUG] 14:07:10.441 Execution getVersion
[DEBUG] 14:07:10.441 Execution execute
[INFO] 14:07:13.841 Process project properties
[DEBUG] 14:07:13.872 Process project properties (done) | time=31ms
[INFO] 14:07:13.947 Load project repositories
[DEBUG] 14:07:13.973 GET 200 http://sonar.acme.com/batch/project.protobuf?key=com.acme%3Aproject | time=23ms
[INFO] 14:07:14.841 Load project repositories (done) | time=888ms
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.290 Available languages:
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.299   * CSS => "css"
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.299   * SCSS => "scss"
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.299   * Less => "less"
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.299   * Java => "java"
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.300   * Web => "web"
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.300   * JSON => "json"
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.300   * JavaScript => "js"
[INFO] 14:07:15.364 Load quality profiles
[DEBUG] 14:07:15.490 GET 200 http://sonar.acme.com/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=com.acme%3Aproject | time=90ms
[INFO] 14:07:15.852 Load quality profiles (done) | time=488ms
[INFO] 14:07:18.500 Load active rules
[DEBUG] 14:07:18.741 GET 200 http://sonar.acme.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AV4XP1MKUliByQMuS3Nj&p=1&ps=500 | time=215ms
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: project-dev@mailman.acme.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

There's nothing else in the log file. There's nothing in the Jenkins log file. There's nothing in Sonar log files. All of the search.protobuf's are returning 200s.... If I re-run the build, it often succeeds, but sometimes still fails. There are no other jobs using Sonar at that point, and still hit or miss. I really am at wits end for what to check at this point. Everything is up to date... Please advise.

Comment: Given the location of your error this is likely a problem between your analyzer and SonarQube, i.e. on your network. But adding `-X` to your `mvn` command should get you more details.

Comment: I do have `-X` here, that's why I even have those details about about the GET requests. There are no more details than this... I'll add more of the log but there's no error message, there's no error stack trace (I also have `-e` enabled for `mvn`).

Comment: Hmm... I just realized that your GET is 200.

Comment: Yes, this whole scenario is very odd. I don't think the problem is on the SonarQube side given those 200 response codes. Is there any way in the Maven plugin that I can enable even more debug information? It looks like an exception is being swallowed and unreported.

Comment: And why not just `sonar:sonar`?

Comment: I'm just fully qualifying the goal. Sonar has released so many Maven plugins under a variety of groupIds, I just wanted to be explicit in the invocation and to avoid confusion in this SO question. :)